# How to get an uploaded file creation date in hunchentoot?

Tags: web, lisp, common-lisp, hunchentoot

I use hunchentoot web server, and upload files there. It stores a file into a temporary location (/tmp/hunchentoot/hunchentoot-XX), and sets the modification and creation date to **now**. How can I get an original creation date of the file received?

Comment: I don't think this is ever being sent... I don't see this info mentioned anywhere in the standard: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2 So, unless you can have a fat client in a language other then JavaScript that can interact with client filesystem and ask it about the time the file was saved, I don't think it would be possible...

Comment: Some files embed that kind of information, e.g. JPEGs are often wrapped with Exif info that includes metadata related to dates. But it's not transmitted with a normal HTTP upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The date is not sent over HTTP at all, it does not depend on your server.
2) You can not expect to always have correct date information from client.

If file format contains date then parse the format. Do this if you are sure format won't be tampered with by malisious user.

If you trust the user let him select date manually.